# Extract Decimal Value From A String

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have **12.00 Php** as a string and I'd like to get 12.00 only. Can someone please help me with this? I find it hard to Google for this. *TryParse* or any conversion doesn't work, or return 0.

```
        Dim i As String = "12.00Php"
```

Comment: Will it always be in the format "<number>Php"?

Comment: @shree.pat18 not necessarily. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+.\d+")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("12.00php")
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
End If
```